# php session, value display dont work

Tags: php, session

I have made php session, and i have problems with how to display it.

Actually here's the whole code (but variables are in Slovenian language and its too much to change every one of it, so sorry about it).

My login.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header ("Location: index1.php");
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $uname = $_POST['uporabnisko1'];
    $pword = $_POST['geslo1'];

    $_SESSION['uporabniskoime1'] = $_POST['uporabnisko1'];

    $user_name = "root";
    $pass_word = "";
    $database = "spletnabaza";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM uporabnik WHERE uporabnisko = '$_POST[uporabnisko1]' AND geslo = '$_POST[geslo1]'";
        $izpisImena ="SELECT '$ime' FROM uporabnik WHERE uporabnisko = '$_POST[uporabnisko1]' AND geslo = '$_POST[geslo1]'";
        $_SESSION['imeuporabnika'] = $izpisImena;
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($result) {
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
                header ("Location: Stranzaindexom.php");
            }
            else {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = "";
                header ("Location: index1.php");
            }   
        }
        else {
            $errorMessage = "Napaka pri vpisu";
        }

    mysql_close($db_handle);

    }

    else {
        $errorMessage = "Napaka pri vpisu";
    }

}


?>
```

My signup.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header ("Location: index1.php");
}

$uname = "";
$pword = "";
$errorMessage = "";
$num_rows = 0;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $name1 = $_POST['ime'];
    $surname = $_POST['priimek'];
    $uname = $_POST['uporabnisko'];
    $pword = $_POST['geslo'];

    $_SESSION['geslo1'] = $_POST['geslo'];
    $_SESSION['uporabniskoime'] = $_POST['uporabnisko'];

    $uLength = strlen($uname);
    $pLength = strlen($pword);

    if ($uLength >= 3 && $uLength <= 20) {
        $errorMessage = "";
    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = $errorMessage . "Uporabniško ime mora biti dolgo od 3 do 20 znakov". "<BR>";
    }

    if ($pLength >= 3 && $pLength <= 16) {
        $errorMessage = "";
    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = $errorMessage . "Geslo mora biti dolgo od 3 do 20 znakov" . "<BR>";
    }

    if ($errorMessage == "") {

    $user_name = "root";
    $pass_word = "";
    $database = "spletnabaza";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM uporabnik WHERE uporabnisko = $uname";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            $errorMessage = "To uporabnisko ime že obstaja!";
        }       
        else {

            $SQL = "INSERT INTO uporabnik (id, ime, priimek, uporabnisko, geslo) VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[ime]', '$_POST[priimek]', '$_POST[uporabnisko]', '$_POST[geslo]')";

            $result = mysql_query($SQL);

            mysql_close($db_handle);

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = "1";

            header ("Location: ../index1.php");
        }
    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = "Database Not Found";
    }
    }
}
?>
```

And than my file in Stranzaindexom.php where i want to display the variables:
At top:

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>
```

In middle:
    Pozdravljen/-a:

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['imeuporabnika'];
?>
```

And when i'm signed in my page with root i get printed:

> Pozdravljen/-a: SELECT 'ime' FROM uporabnik WHERE uporabnisko= 'root' AND
>   geslo= ''

Insted of Pozdravljen/-a, professor. (professor is the name of root username)

Did i miss something ?

Comment: Where do you use [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Comment: Its at the beginning of every .php file

Comment: Could you post some more of your code? Now we can only guess what you have and what not.

Comment: If you echo($name) , does that contains the name? Are you sure it's retrieved from the database?

Comment: This isn't even close to correct. You don't just have a query and then the values from the database magically appear for you. You have to execute your query and retrieve its values. You also have a syntax error in the query so it wouldn't work anyway. Plus there are huge security holes in this code.

Comment: I think you need to do a lot more basics of PHP before jumping in to an application. You need to learn about forms, sessions, database queries and (quite evidently) how to secure any data your application takes and uses.

Comment: I update my question, these is full code of login.php and signup.php where i have all those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing any of the above queries, check the user input ($_POST variables). This can be done easily with the `mysql_real_escape_string` function. You might also want to use `strip_tags()` and `trim()` functions. For example:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

The mysql_* functions are deprecated, I would recommend you to start using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or, even better in my opinion, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Also, your queries won't work, here is a working example:

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '{$name}'";
```

Don't store any session before actually loggin in or registering. Do this after the user has succesfully registered or logged in. Also don't store any valuable variables like a password, just the user_id would be enough for you. You could easily check if a user is logged in:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    //User is logged in
} else {
    //User is not logged in
}
```

Also, only connect to the DB once and use `session_start()` once per script. Even prettier would be to do this in a file named `config.php`. Then simply do this in the beginning of your scripts:

```
require_once('config.php');
```

There are more things, but this will give you a good start and enough to work on :-). Good luck.